# StackOverFlowError when removing components from a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, stack-overflow

I have a JPanel that contains other panels with different GUI components including buttons with action listeners. At some point I want to remove some of the components and add new ones. So I try to remove all of the components on the main JPanel and then add the new ones. When I run the `removeAll()` method I get a stack overflow error. I also tried removing one component at a time but I still get that problem. Tried also different combinations with in/re/validate but the old components are not removed. Here is what I tried last:

```
public void updateSuites() {
    removeAll();

    //for(int i = 0; i < getComponentCount(); i++)
      //remove(getComponent(i));

    invalidate();
    showGui();

    revalidate();
    repaint();
}
```

What's the problem here?

EDIT:

So here is the code again:

```
public void updateSuites() {

    for(int i = 0; i < getComponentCount(); i++)
      if(!(getComponent(i) instanceof ControlPanel))
        remove(getComponent(i));

    invalidate();
    showGui();

    revalidate();
    repaint();
}
```

I have a class that extends JPanel and I have more panels and components on it. I also have a ControlPanel with some buttons and things on it. So the idea is that when a button on the ControlPanel is pressed, it calls this method on the parent panel which is supposed to remove everything on it except the ControlPanel itself (from where the call comes). But I get stack overflow:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.removeInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.removeInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.removeInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.removeInternal(Unknown Source)
```

EDIT 2:

I did a little debugging and discovered the following: I have an array of JPanels that are added onto the current panel. So it is not a problem to remove the children of the array JPanels but the problem occurs when I try to remove an array JPanel. The code looks something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
      panels[i] = new JPanel();
      // add components to panels[i]
      add(panels[i]);
}
```

So if I run

```
for(int i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
      remove(panels[i]);
}
```

I get the stack overflow error.

Comment: Just check your stacktrace. You will see what kind of looping you do. We cannot solve this with the current information

Comment: Where's your recursion? You might not realize it, but it's there somewhere lurking in your code. Also, would you be better served by using a CardLayout to swap views?

Comment: Hmm, the call to the method comes from a button that is on the same panel. Could it be the cause?

Comment: @RegedUser00x From the very, very  tiny bit of information you have provided, it is impossible for anyone to answer your question. Stackoverflow is the result of an infinite recursion between one or more methods. Either post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), either you will be stuck with yourself to find the problem.

Comment: OK, I updated the description of the problem.

Comment: @RegedUser00x: You've already been told that you shouldn't iterate forward through an array when removing items. Why are you still doing this??

Answer (score 4):

I would try this:

```
for (int i = getComponentCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    remove(getComponent(i));
}
```

You're calling `getComponentCount` after every deletion, which reduces the count by 1.